# How to pull and reference data from a given cell in a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, reference

I am working on a tool for my department that, in the end, will look at people's google calendars over a set date range and populate a spreadsheet with a list of all the scheduled meetings they had during that date range.

The code currently works with a hard-coded date and email to draw from, but gives the above error when I have it reference a spreadsheet cell (people will be inputting their email address and date range to draw from into a fillable form).

I have tried using getRange(), getValue(), and getCell(), and none of them have worked.

The problem code is as such:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var inputSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("InputCleaner");

var outputSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("RawData");

var mycal = inputSheet.getCell(5,2,1,1);

var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("July 18, 2019 23:59:59 CST"), {search: '-project123'});
```

When I attempt to execute the code above, it gives the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getCell in object Sheet. (line 32, file "Code")

The code above functions perfectly if line 3, instead of referencing a cell, just has the email address itself like so:

```
var mycal = "example.email@gmail.com";
```

But I need it to be able to draw the email address from a specific cell in the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function function1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ish=ss.getSheetByName("InputCleaner");
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName("RawData");
  var mycal=ish.getRange(5,2).getValue();
  var cal=CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  var events=cal.getEvents(new Date("January 12, 2014 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("July 18, 2019 23:59:59 CST"), {search: '-project123'});//not sure about this line
}
```

Here's a function to display your calendar Id's:

```
function displayCalendarInfo()
{
  var cals=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var s='Calendar Information';
  for(var i=0;i<cals.length;i++)
  {
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Name: %s Id: %s', cals[i].getName(),cals[i].getId());
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1200).setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Calendar Data');
}
```

Comment: That worked in extracting the email address from the spreadsheet, but it is still giving an error for some reason [TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of null. (line 53, file "Code")]

When I check the debugger, there is now an email address saved under mycal (it wasn't being saved before, so that's an improvement), bit shows null for the variable cal.

Which is quite confusing, as when I used a straight email address in this way (in the same format as mycal is now), it worked fine.

Comment: Then I would guess that you calendarId is incorrect.